# Spring Boot throws an SQL Syntax exception

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin

I am testing new endpoints on my API and getting an error that confuses me a bit.

```
2022-08-24 11:51:54.283  WARN 9836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2022-08-24 11:51:54.283 ERROR 9836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE) FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-01') AND ((null ' at line 1
2022-08-24 11:51:54.292 ERROR 9836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE) FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-01') AND ((null ' at line 1
```

The confusing part for me is that I don't understand where it gets the first part of the query `WHERE)` in the error message.

**Repo**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) AND ((:code IS NULL OR rate_code = :code) AND rate > 0)", nativeQuery = true)
    fun getByDateRange(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, code: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<RateEntity>
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/historic")
    fun ratesForDateRange(
        @RequestParam startDate: Optional<Date>,
        @RequestParam endDate: Optional<Date>,
        @RequestParam(required = false) code: String?,
        @RequestParam(required = false) pageNumber: Int?
    ): Page<RateEntity> {
        val lastDate = Date.valueOf(START_DATE)
        val page = pageNumber ?: 0
        println(code)
        return repo.getByDateRange(
            startDate.orElse(lastDate),
            endDate.orElse(UtilFunctions.getCurrentSQLDate()),
            code,
            PageRequest.of(page, 50)
        )
    }
```

When I use the wrong `code` in request URL `/api/v1/historic?startDate=2022-1-1&endDate=2022-3-1&code=abc` I get an empty page as expected.

When I use the right `code` in request URL `/api/v1/historic?startDate=2022-1-1&endDate=2022-3-1&code=suv` and there are records between specified dates, I get the page with results as expected.

However, when I don't specify the code in request URL `/api/v1/historic?startDate=2022-1-1&endDate=2022-3-1` I get this exception.

I use MySQL for Database and if use this query directly in CLI it works as expected.
For example this query

`SELECT * FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-01') AND ((null IS NULL OR rate_code = null) AND rate > 0);`

returns all results for specified date range as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem with date_and_time in spring boot.

You are comparing two dates whereas the actual values saved are **dateAndTime**, which spring can not compare. Therefore, you should cast the date field as follow:

```
CAST(date as DATE)
```

Complete Query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM rates WHERE (CAST(date as DATE) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) AND ((:code IS NULL OR rate_code = :code) AND rate > 0)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, already found the solution. The problem was not with parameters or initial query, but with the query created by hibernate for pagination. See my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've already found where the problem lies and fixed it. Probably posted too soon.

After some more testing I found out that the exception occurs when amount of results is >= page size (50 in my case).

So after displaying hibernate queries with:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

I found this:

```
Hibernate: SELECT count(WHERE) FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND ((? IS NULL OR rate_code = ?) AND rate > 0)
```

That's where `WHERE)` comes from, which is obviously a syntax error.

The fix was to add custom count query like this:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) AND ((:code IS NULL OR currency_code = :code) AND rate > 0)",
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM rates WHERE (date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) AND ((:code IS NULL OR currency_code = :code) AND rate > 0)",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun getByDateRange(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, code: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<RateEntity>
```